# Prove the matrices $ A $ and $ B $ commute

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $ A $ and $ B $ be matrices in $ M_n(\mathbb{F}) $ such that $ A^2B + AB^2 = I $. I already proved that $ A, A + B, B $ are invertible and that $ (A + B)^3 - A^3 - B^3 = 3I $.

I am now asked to prove that if $ A $ and $ B $ are symmetric matrices, then they commute.

Could you give me a clue?

Comment: $ (A^2B + AB^2)^T =BA^2+B^2A= I $

Answer (score 1):

$A^2B+AB^2=I=A(AB+B^2)\implies AB=-B^2+A^{-1}$.

Take transpose with $A^t=A,B^t=B, (A^{-1})^t=A^{-1}$,
$$BA=-B^2+A^{-1}=AB.$$

Comment: How did you get $ BA = -B^2 + A^{-1} $ ?

Comment: @talopl Take transpose of $AB$.